# Linq To Sql Left outer join - filtering null results

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, inner-join

I'd like to reproduce the following SQL into C# LinqToSql

```
SELECT TOP(10) Keywords.*
FROM         Keywords 
LEFT OUTER JOIN IgnoreWords 
  ON Keywords.WordID = IgnoreWords.ID
WHERE  (DomainID = 16673) 
  AND (IgnoreWords.Name IS NULL)
ORDER BY [Score] DESC
```

The following C# Linq gives the right answer.
But I can't help think I'm missing something (a better way of doing it?)

```
var query = (from keyword in context.Keywords
     join ignore in context.IgnoreWords 
        on keyword.WordID equals ignore.ID into ignored
     from i in ignored.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where i == null
     where keyword.DomainID == ID
     orderby keyword.Score descending
     select keyword).Take(10);
```

the SQL produced looks something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
       [t0].[DomainID]
     , [t0].[WordID]
     , [t0].[Score]
     , [t0].[Count]
  FROM [dbo].[Keywords] AS [t0]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (  SELECT 1 AS [test]
            , [t1].[ID] 
         FROM [dbo].[IgnoreWords] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2] 
    ON [t0].[WordID] = [t2].[ID] 
WHERE ([t0].[DomainID] = 16673) 
  AND ([t2].[test] IS NULL)
ORDER BY [t0].[Score] DESC
```

How can I get rid of this redundant inner selection?
It's only slightly more expensive but every bit helps!

Comment: `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are more efficient than `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` on SQL Server: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: Have you checked the query plan to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @gabe - Yes there is a measurable difference

Comment: reading this article.  seems highly relevant:
http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do something like this to eliminate the left join and maybe get more efficiency:

```
var query = (from keyword in context.Keywords
             where keyword.DomainID == ID 
             && !(from i in context.IgnoreWords select i.ID).Contains(keyword.WordID)
             orderby keyword.Score descending
             select keyword)
            .Take(10);
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer I just found :)

Comment: Both this answer and the code in question are pretty straight forward.  Anyone have an article that posts benchmark results on these to methods vs. one another?